# Sync views between pouchdb and couchdb

Tags: node.js, couchdb, pouchdb, cloudant

I've been able to sync data from my cloudant instance to my nodejs based pouchdb, however I need to setup a secondary search index and therefore I created a view on the couchdb instance however I am unable to see it in my synced pouchdb instance.

I see it in cloudant, in all documents, however after syncing and calling alldocs on pouchdb, it's not there.  Also, i'm using the pouchdb-find plugin and I can't reference the secondary index search fields.  Of course from pouchdb if if set the secondary index, it works fine.

Am I missing something?  Does sync not replicate design docs in PouchDB?  If not, what's the best way to create a persistent secondary index?

Any good docs for this?  (Nolan....?)  Speaking of docs, or support, is there an IRC room or some other live support for couchdb from the user community?

Thanks for your attention,
Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pouchdb-find is a reimplementation of Cloudant Query Language, not their search index (which is what I think you're talking about). It's also not done; I've only written about half of the operators. :) You may also want to try the pouchdb-quick-search plugin, which is for full-text search.

In general, the advice I usually give people is to not sync design documents at all – just replicate using a filter to avoid syncing design docs. Then you can create design documents that are optimized for whatever platform you happen to be on (PouchDB, CouchDB, Cloudant, the various PouchDB plugins, etc.).

And yeah, we are usually pretty responsive inside of the IRC channel and on the mailing list, but it's a small operation because we aren't sponsored by Cloudant or Couchbase or anybody. The core PouchDB team are all hobbyists. :)

Comment: Ah gotcha.  Thanks lots for the quick reply Nolan.  You are truly a champion of pouchdb/couchdb.  I just wanted to make sure I was not overlooking some way to do it.  I appreciate the confirmation and saving me additional time I'd have lost continuing to look.

Comment: Nolan, actually I don't see the design doc being sync'ed.  as I said, I've added a design doc on cloudant, however when i sync to my local pouch instance, I don't see the design doc appearing in pouch.  I do however see it cloudant gui (of course).  Is there something special I need to do to have it come over when syncing?

Comment: Also you mention to create design docs optimized for whatever platform?  It's simply a secondary index, would it be done differently to optimize over various platforms?

Comment: By "platform" I mean CouchDB vs PouchDB vs Cloudant etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is stupid but, does the user that access couch has the admin role? Only admins can see and edit design documents.

Comment: Yeah, this is what Nolan mentioned last night.  The auth info I was using did not.  Nolan did also point out that the secondary index would not be automatically rebuilt anyway.

Comment: I did not saw Nolan's comment. The important thing is, was that the problem?

Comment: Actually, I can't explain why, but all day it's been syncing design docs and all, even using a new user who only has r/w perms (not admin or replicate) to a new in-mem db.  The problem is that even with the design doc/view/index, it can not be used by pouchdb, likely because that part has not been implemented yet (mentioned by Nolan in his earlier response).

Comment: I agree with Nolan that is not a good idea to share design documents. But views are actually supported by couchdb, so I don't understand what are you talking about.